# Pronunciation of "nomenclature"

Tags: pronunciation

"Nomenclature".

OED has two pronunciations for it:

> nə(ʊ)ˈmɛŋklətʃə (nuh-men-cla-cher)

and

> ˈnəʊmənˌkleɪtʃə (nomen-clay-cher)

I use the former of the two, albeit without any real reason.

Which is the most-oft used and are there geographical preferences?

Comment: The difference in these is the stress: *nuh-MEN-cluh-cher* and *NO-men-CLAY-cher*.  In the U.S., I don't think I ever hear *nuh-MEN-cluh-cher*. So my guess is that the first is mainly British (in which case you have a very good reason to use it). And the speakers at [forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com/word/nomenclature/) seem to agree; the first is used by the Brits, the second by the American, and the Canadian says both.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks for letting me know the U.S. preference.

Comment: @Peter: Absolutely right! As confirmed by [Cambridge dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/nomenclature). But equally, I don't think I ever hear the US version (so it sounds *totally* weird to me, as I'm sure my version does to you). I think maybe it's just one of those words we *read* much more often than we *hear*. And even though we (hopefully! :) don't move our lips when we read, we still "hear" using the inner voice. Reinforcing our own particular native preferences, which in practice are rarely contravened by real-world conversations, etc.

Comment: Yes, I definitely read it more than say it.  Didn't realise Cambridge shows pronunciation by Br.Eng and Am.Eng. - I will have to check there in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these two pronunciation stems from which syllables are stressed; the difference in vowels follows by the process of reduction of unstressed vowels in English.

As discussed in the comments, and verified by Cambridge dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/nomenclature)

> no-MEN-cla-ture is the British pronunciation,
>   NO-men-CLA-ture is the American pronunciation.